# Disappearing data/ variables/ realisations

Tags: stata

I am a beginner in Stata and I have a problem. I was trying to `generate` two new variables. But after I did so, every realisation dropped. Could somebody help me understand this problem?

```
. gen FRA2017=E1004

. keep if inlist(FRA2017, "FRA_2017")
(2,032 observations deleted)

. tab FRA2017
no observations

. tab E1004
no observations

. drop FRA2017

. tab E1004
no observations

. tab GER2017
no observations
```

I want to `generate` a new variable without deleting or leaving the new and old variable empty.

Comment: What your data are like and quite what the problem is are not clear. Also, your original text implied wanting to `generate` "to new variables", presumably meaning two new variables, but only one is created here.  On the face of it there were no values of "FRA_2017" in either your old or your new variable, so on your instructions everything was `drop`ped (nothing was kept).  Show us please the results of `tab E1004` beforehand.

Comment: At a guess you want to keep observations which are something like `FRA_2017` but Stata's comparison is utterly literal, If what you want is different in any way (leading or trailing spaces, different punctuation, variations in use of upper and lower case) then Stata won't correct you, and will just `drop` everything (= `keep` nothing).

Answer (score 2):

The first line defines a new variable within the dataset, which you call `FRA2017`, and assigns it the value of the existing variable `E1004` for all observations. When you try to subset the data to keep only observations for which `FRA2017` equals the value `"FRA_2017"`, all of the observations are deleted, evidently because none of the values of the variable `FRA2017` in fact equal `"FRA_2017"`.

Once you have `drop`ped all observations, then nothing can be tabulated.

I'm not sure what your intention is otherwise. Perhaps you can add some sample data?